# Proper implementation of multi-threaded + socket application

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, unity-game-engine

I have a server and a client application, here's how it's currently implemented: The server has a loop, in its own thread, that listens for new connections through a TcpListener. If someone connects, it passes the TcpClient to a loop that listens to that TcpClient specifically, and handles all interaction with that user through NetworkStream.

On the client, I have a TcpClient that connects to the server. It's my understanding that I need to branch it to a different thread, since any IO will put it in to blocking mode, and I can't let it stop the main thread.

So far, am I understanding it correctly? Is there an easier way to asure asynchronous communication without stopping the main thread for either program?

Either way, for my main question: How do I make sure all of these threads and sockets are properly disposed of? If a program exits while it's still in blocking mode, it seems to freeze. So how do I abort all IO on the socket and tell the infinite loop in the child threads that we're done?

This is also a Unity3d project by the way, in case that changes anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handing off each new connection to its own thread could limit your scalability down the line.  Also there's no reason to require thread handoff for I/O in the client.

You can resolve both issues by using async I/O.  `BeginConnect/EndConnect` on the client, `BeginRead/EndRead, BeginWrite/EndWrite` on the server side for reads and writes.

Then everything can be event-driven without any need for new threads of your own.  Connect completion triggers first async read, then each read completion posts a new async read call on that socket - writes are always deterministic from your POV anyway.

Closing your sockets will results in pending reads/writes exiting out with an error, and then you should be able to exit the process cleanly.  Be careful that you implement appropriate locking (likely `lock()` will be all you need) to ensure sockets are not used anywhere after they have been closed.

Comment: You have given me A LOT to research! Thanks, I figured I was probably doing something very impractical.

Answer (score 1):

You should have two separate threads, one for `TcpListener` and other for the `TcpClient` that are running on there own. When initializing a new thread make its [IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property to true so that if the application terminates it will terminates too.

```
Thread listenerThread = new Thread(ListenerLoop);
listenerThread.IsBackground = true;
listernerThread.Start();
```

You can use `Task` if you are using 4.0 or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` instead of thread.

Comment: Don't you mean N+1 threads? One for the listener, one for each client?

Comment: @EJP: yes, one for each tcpClient.